# Naming conventions for classes when you have two classes with the same name

Tags: java, naming-conventions, hierarchy

I need to create a hierarchy of different kinds of vehicles.

[image]

I'm not sure exactly how I am supposed to name each of the different types of cars. My first thought was to name them `FordTruck` and `FordCar`, but that seemed like a bit too much for each class.

My other idea was to just create separate packages for cars and trucks, so that the names won't interfere. Having the same name in different packages seems to have the disadvantage of less readable code when trying to implement methods that use both `Cars` and `Trucks`.

What is the convention and what is the best practice for naming the files?

Comment: in this case it can be single class implementing both Car and Truck

Comment: If you go with the suffix way, at least respect the standard Java naming conventions: `FordCar` and `FordTruck`. Class names never contain underscores.

Comment: Clean up your abstraction.  Dodge and Ford are classifications of a vehicle manufacturer; not a vehicle type.  You are attempting to represent two abstractions with one class hierarchy.  Use one hierarchy per abstraction

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Make is better suited as an Enum of Vehicle instead of being a Class itself.

Edit: I'm going to expand upon this a little bit.  You make a Class to represent nouns (things), the Make (Dodge, Ford, Chevy, etc...) is an adjective, something that describes a noun. Instead of giving it its own class, you make it a property of the class it is describing. A String would do as well, I just chose Enum because I prefer them.

Answer (score 1):

Make should be a flag inside Truck and Car, not a class. As Mike N said, and Enum constant would do.